# Print a Google Books preview direct to a printer and not to PDF or as a file

Tags: printing, google-books

How do I print a preview in Google Books straight to the printer and not to file or saved as a PDF?

My younger brother is researching English literature and asked me how to print a book preview from Google Books. He doesn't want it to be saved or printed to a digital file format and instead want a hard copy paper print.

Where do I go to print these previews?

UPDATE 1: My younger brother and I tried to download the book preview but that seems to be impossible, my younger brother even tried to copy paste the text from that pdf book to MS Word but that didn't work. I asked my younger brother to copy paste that book preview link to me so that I can paste it here, I'll give this question bounty, hopefully someone will give us a better solution alternative for this.

UPDATE 2: [This is the link that he needs to print some pages from it](http://books.google.com/books?id=fE8JDzVyTLIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=developing+reading+skills&hl=id&ei=_VWVTo-nNMforQf1mdGbBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. It is a limited preview, the author has not given Google Books the rights to print or save.

If it were a Full Preview you would see something similar to the following in the case of [Pride and Prejudice](http://books.google.com/ebooks?id=kQ0mAAAAMAAJ) on the page

[image: Read Now]

And then on the output page near the bottom,

[image: PDF Download]

Please see [Google Books Usage](http://books.google.com/googlebooks/screenshots.html#fullview) page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because it is still copyrighted.

You would have to scroll through and take a series of screen shots with something like MS Onenote, which would be laborious.

Comment: Any references or sources here?